# How to add and use resources in silverlight Windows Phone application?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, resources

I see there's an option to add resource file (.resx). I can create .resx file and add images there. Now I want change image1.source (in .cs file) to image.png from resource file. How can I do this? My BuildAction is set to 'Page' and I prefer to not change this value...

Comment: and why I can't create BitmapImage object in .cs ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this by adding hidden (Visibility=Collapse) images: image2, image3
In image1_Tap() method I have:

```
if(image1.source==image2.source)  
image1.source=image3.source;  
else image1.source=image2.source;
```

Comment: Better way to do this: add image with some source (for example picture.png), delete this image. picture.png is still available in application.      `image2.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/App;component/Images/picture.png",UriKind.Relative));`